# Large-scale processing of seralized Integer objects

Tags: java, c++, lucene, deserialization, large-data

I have a large data set in the following format:

In total, there are 3687 object files. Each of which contains 2,000,000 records. Each file is 42MB in size.

Each record contains the following:

- An id  (Integer value)
- Value1 (Integer)
- Value2 (Integer)
- Value3 (Integer)

The content of each file is not sorted or ordered in any way as they are observed during a data collection process.

Ideally, I want to build an index for this data. (Indexed by the id) which would mean the following:

1. Dividing the set of ids into manageable chunks.
2. Scanning the files to get data related to the current working set of ids.
3. Build the index.
4. Go over the next chunk and repeat 1,2,3.

To me this sounds fine but loading 152GB back and forth is time-consuming and wonder about the best possible approach or even whether Java is actually the right language to use for such a process.

I've 256GB of ram and 32 cores on my machine.

---

**Update:**
Let me modify this, putting aside I/O, and assuming the file is in-memory in a byte array.

What would be the fastest possible way to decode a 42MB Object file that have 2,000,000 records and each record contains 4 Integers serialized.

Comment: "I want to build an index" -- Why? What do you want to index? Is there anything you want to calculate? Will the calculation be faster with the index at all? And the most important: are the indexes of RDBMS solutions bad for you?

Comment: @Csq thanks for asking. Yes I want the index to be able to calculate more statistics later and not on-the-fly. DBMS is not my current option.

Comment: Exactly what are you indexing? the ID or the Value1, Value2, Value3? Or something else?

Comment: @Mats The OP says _indexed by the id_.

Comment: Doh. Thanks for the edit of the text, it got a bit more readable now. I was staring straight at the "index by id" and still didn't see it...

Comment: I would probably hold as much of it in ram as I could (seemingly all in your case).  I would build a small single threaded program using a small subset of the data to test your algorithm.  Once you know it works, I would simply put an OpenMP wrapper around your while, or for loop and let your 32 core (perhaps 64 thread) machine crunch away at it!  Look at OpenMP it is VERY simple to get a model threaded once you understand it CAN be threaded, and after you get your single threaded model to work properly.  That being said I would use C++.  Java is pretty easily threaded also, but will be slower

Comment: @trumpetlicks thanks. I'm working on this and seems to be doing fine in terms of speed for reading/processing. One hour completed the whole data but I've not yet managed memory well to let it index the data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I would do is just load up each file and store the id into some sort of sorted structure - std::map perhaps [or Java's equivalent, but given that it's probably about 10-20 lines of code to read in the filename and then read the contents of the file into a map, close the file and ask for the next file, I'd probably just write the C++ to do that].

I don't really see what else you can/should do, unless you actually want to load it into a dbms - which I don't think is at all unreasonable of a suggestion.

Comment: Sure, that is an obvious thing to do. 7 secs per file means 7 hours to complete reading and decoding all files. You cannot leave all data on memory ( the hashmap) so you need to dump it to disk at some point and re-read again later to merger. in short this is a solution i've done but not an ideal one.

Comment: It takes 7 seconds to process 2000000 records of a 42MB text file? Seems a lot. I just filled a file with 2M random numbers, read them all and stored in a std::map, and it took 5.3 seconds on my machine - my file however is nearly twice the size of yours, 77MB [because random numbers get pretty large most of the time]. And my machine is hardly some super-duper 32-core beast. Just a now fairly old quad core AMD machine. Admittedly with 16GB of RAM, but still.

Comment: I also tried underorered_map, and it's about a second faster - 4.7 seconds total time.

Comment: And changing the `while(cin << id << a << b << c)` to `scanf("%d %d %d %d", &id, &a, &b, &c)` improves the speed by a factor of four. So you may want to look at the "read the file" part of the code, more than the "insert into a table".

Comment: Thanks Mats. I agree that reading the file and perhaps the file format are the parts to focus on.

Comment: File reading was the issue. I used the nio package and optimized the code.

Answer (score 2):

You've made a very poor choice of file format. I would convert the lot from serialized Integers to binary ints written with DataOutputStream.writeInt(), and read them with DataInputStream.readInt(). With buffered streams underneath in both cases. You will save masses of disk space, which will therefore save you I/O time as well, and you also save all the serialization overhead time. And change your collection software to use this format in future. The conversion will take a while, but it only happens once.

Or else use a database as suggested, again with native ints rather than serialized objects.

Comment: I agree with you EJP that the file format was a bad idea. I would try this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. it seems the better way of doing it is to use some kind of DBMS. Load all your data into database, and you can leverage its indexing, storage and querying facility. Ofcourse this depends on what is your requirement -- and whether or now a DBMS solution suits this

Comment: Thanks for the advice. DBMS will take forever :) I've tried it in the past with a smaller dataset. Building an indexer for such data is my current option and I think is more efficient only if scanning such data could get faster.

Comment: Hmm how about non relational DB? Or some caching library like EHCache? If the problem is with memory consumption, you need some sort of paging algorithm to avoid heap blowout (keep only pages you need in the memory & relegate those you don't to disk)

Comment: For large data sets, one normally wants to cache to disk (i.e. some form of DB) as LITTLE as you can to keep performance up.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your available memory is > than your dataset and you want very high performance, have you considered Redis?  It's well suited to operations on simple data structures and the performance is very fast.

Just be a bit careful about letting java do default serialization when storing values.  I've previously run into issues with my primitives getting autoboxed prior to serialization.